# Creating Test Suite dynamically in NUnit

Tags: nunit

I would like to create a test suite using NUnit.

In java, I could use the name of the classes and do something like this:

```
TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Class.forName({Name of my test class here})));
```

In NUnit, I have a TestSuite created (from NUnit.Core) but I can't create Tests dynamically and add them to the suite.

I appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In NUnit 2.4.4, there is a new feature - the [Suite Attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.6.2) that allows you to return an array of tests as opposed to using the `TestSuite` class in previous versions.  To add tests, it would look something like this:

```
[Suite] 
public static IEnumerable Suite
{
   get
   {
      ArrayList suite = new ArrayList();
      suite.Add(new AddAll());
      return suite;
   }
}
```